# what is the difference between the words intended and intending?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the words *intended* and *intending* in these sentences?

- A*n intending swimmer was prevented from entering the sea by coastguards because the tides were dangerous*.
- *The book failed to reach its intended audience.*

Can both the words be used interchangeably like 'an intended swimmer...' and  '....intending audience' without changing their meaning?

Comment: The swimmer is *intending* to swim. The book is *intended* for the audience.

Comment: What do dictionaries say? They have different meanings. Who has the intention in each sentence? The 'intend ... noun'? //// I've checked and seen dictionary examples of 'an intending X'  for 'a person intending to be an X / do some Xing', but do others think OP's first example is idiomatic?

Comment: It's a question of who's doing the intending. Who wants what? If it's the subject who intends to do something, they're _intending_. But if somebody else is the intender, then the subject is intended, since their intentions are irrelevant.

Comment: These are relatively simple tenses of a fairly well-behaved verb.  Study the difference between the "-ed" and "-ing" suffixes for verbs.

Answer (score 1):

Intending is used as an adjective to describe "planning or meaning to do something", whereas usually, intended is used as an adjective to designate the noun as a "desired" object of something.

For example, "the intending swimmer", suggests that the swimmer intends to swim.
"The intended audience" suggests that the audience is actually the "desired" object of some other, unreferenced noun.